# How to remove [Symbol] fields from winston@3 logger output?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

Here is a demo code for winston@3 logger:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston")
const { combine, timestamp, prettyPrint } = format

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(timestamp(), prettyPrint({ colorize: true }))
})

logger.add(new transports.Console())

logger.info("test message", { data: { a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: new Date() } })
```

It prints:

```
{ data: { a: 1, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], d: 2018-07-17T09:38:43.253Z },
  level: 'info',
  message: 'test message',
  timestamp: '2018-07-17T09:38:43.253Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'info',
  [Symbol(splat)]:
   [ { data: { a: 1, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], d: 2018-07-17T09:38:43.253Z } } ] }
```

I'd like to remove some fields from output: [Symbot(level)], [Symbot(splat)], so I'd like to have such output:

```
{ data: { a: 1, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], d: 2018-07-17T09:38:43.253Z },
  level: 'info',
  message: 'test message',
  timestamp: '2018-07-17T09:38:43.253Z' }
```

Comment: Did you found a solution? Same issue here.

Comment: Any update? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can modify log output and its format. Here is the official doc : https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#streams-objectmode-and-info-objects

Here is the example:

```
logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
    level       : 'error',
    prettyPrint : true,
    silent      : false,
    timestamp   : true,
    json        : false
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it prints an error:

`throw new Error('Invalid transport, must be an object with a log method.');`

Here is a demo code:

`
const winston = require("winston")

const logger = winston.createLogger()

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  level: "error",
  prettyPrint: true,
  silent: false,
  timestamp: true,
  json: false
})

logger.info("test message", { data: { a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: new Date() } })
`

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
removeSymbols(meta) {
  return Object.entries(meta).reduce(
    (acc: LogMessage, [k, v]) =>
      typeof k === 'symbol' ? acc : ((acc[k] = v), acc),
    {}
  );
}
```